# clean up corrupted comma separated data in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have table called entity and it has column lsofsubentity which has comma separated values.

for eg if entity A has 3 sub entity (B,C,D) then it will have data like B,C,D in that column.

but due to some logical issue in the code the data inside is corrupted it has values like B,,,,C,D. this happened because when you unassign the sub entity from the entity it only removed the id it didn't remove the , along with it.

can anyone please help me how i can remove the extra , in this value?.

I tried reading many posts where the used unnest string_to_array then remove null from array then again convert it to array_to_string but I was not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a RegEx to cleanup the fields:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET some_field = regexp_replace(some_field, '(^,+)|(,+$)|((?<=,),)', '', 'g');
```

The RegEx has three parts:

- Remove all commas at the beginning of the string.
- Remove all commas at the end of the string.
- Remove any comma following another comma.

It's possible someone else has stronger RegEx foo than me hence can simplify the RegEx - but that should work.

PS I would suggest you do a select first, just to check the values look right before doing the update:

```
SELECT some_field, regexp_replace(some_field, '(^,+)|(,+$)|((?<=,),)', '', 'g')
FROM some_table;
```

Comment: Perhaps a repetition of two or more for the multiple comma replacement, `,{2,}`. Either way works.

Comment: Agreed its more efficient to add an additional + i.e.: `(^,+)|(,+$)|((?<=,),+)`